# Remove inserted but unsaved object from Core Data Managed Object Context

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is there a way to remove a single managed object which has already been inserted into a context but not yet saved? I want to remove a single object, not rollback the whole context. I've tried calling `deleteObject:` but it throws an exception since, according to core data, the object doesn't exist in the MOC yet. By looking at core data's inserted objects property I definitely know that it has been inserted and by looking at deleted objects I know that it has been marked for deletion. Essentially I want to "uninsert" the object. Saving first then deleting is not acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out that it is totally legal to call `deleteObject:` on an object that has not yet been persisted. According to Apple's documentation:

> If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is simply removed from the receiver.

My problem was actually a result of the fact that there was a retain cycle due to the managed object's relationships. This was solved by setting the problematic relationships to `nil`.

Note: until you save the MOC the managed object that you just inserted then deleted will appear in both `MOC.insertedObjects` and `MOC.deletedObjects`